# R Dictionaries use strings as values or just use lists?

Tags: r, list, dictionary

I am looking to create a dictionary with strings as keys and a separate set of strings as values in R. Is there a way to do this? I run into issues setting strings as values using `hash`. Should I just use a list instead?

EDIT:

```r
my.dict <- hash::hash(
  keys = c("name1", "name2"),
  values = c("username1", "username2")
)
```

When I do this, my environment shows that my values are all equal to NA.

Instead, I want to be able to access my values by:

```r
my.values <- hash::values(my.dict)
```

So that `my.values` gives me, `username1, username2` when I print it.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expeted output

Comment: *"run into issues"* without details doesn't really help us help you. In the meantime, there is a good discussion of using `list` versus `environment` as a hash table of sorts at https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/03/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-i/. There are three other parts: [part ii](https://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/116325104028/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-ii-in-part-i), [part iii](https://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/116690418898/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-iii-in-part), and [part iv](https://jeffreyhorner.tumblr.com/post/117059271933/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-iv).

Comment: When I try your code, `hash::values(my.dict)` indeed returns a named vector, length two, with those values. Do you mean the literal comma-delimited string, `paste(hash::values(my.dict), collapse = ", ")`?